# what is the difference between shared hint and prallel hint?

Tags: oracle

In the database, I have noticed a query running with shared hint.

```
    SELECT /*+ SHARED (8) */ ID from tab1
```

I execute the query plan to understand more about it , I notice `px send qc` which means parallel

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                 | Name            | Rows     | Bytes     | Cost | Time |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                 | 58773659 | 235094636 | 7389 |      |
|  1 |   PX COORDINATOR          |                 |          |           |      |      |
|  2 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)    | :TQ10000        | 58773659 | 235094636 | 7389 |      |
|  3 |     PX BLOCK ITERATOR     |                 | 58773659 | 235094636 | 7389 |      |
|  4 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | IDX_RTEST3      | 58773659 | 235094636 | 7389 |      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have execute parallel hint and I have got the same results, then what is the different between shared and parallel hint?

```
 select /*+parallel(8) */ ID from tab1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a difference. Oracle-generated code sometimes uses `shared`, but as [that isn't documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-06C047B1-133B-4211-9949-5FE9C0659D44) you should probably stick to `parallel` in your own code.

See [MoS document 2416478.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2416478_1.html) for a bit more information - I can't quote from that because it requires a support contract to view it.

Answer (score 1):

SHARED hint is same as PARALLEL hint, and SHARED(1) works like NOPARALLEL hint to set Degree = 1.

For example:

Query 1:

```
set autot trace

select /*+ SHARED(8) */ * from <user_name>.<table_name>;

105 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1625188644

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time | TQ |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT | | 105 | 10185 | 2 (0)| 00:00:01 | | | |
| 1 | PX COORDINATOR | | | | | | | | |
| 2 | PX SEND QC (RANDOM)| :TQ10000 | 105 | 10185 | 2 (0)| 00:00:01 | Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND) |
| 3 | PX BLOCK ITERATOR | | 105 | 10185 | 2 (0)| 00:00:01 | Q1,00 | PCWC | |
| 4 | TABLE ACCESS FULL| <table_name> | 105 | 10185 | 2 (0)| 00:00:01 | Q1,00 | PCWP | |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Query 2:

```
set autot trace

select /*+ SHARED(1) */ * from <user_name>.<table_name>;

105 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1275100350

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT | | 105 | 10185 | 2 (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 1 | TABLE ACCESS FULL| <table_name> | 105 | 10185 | 2 (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please refer to MOS :(Doc ID 2416478.1)